# Move wordpress sidebar on homepage up to new position

Tags: php, themes, register-sidebar

This should be a simple task, however I am having no such luck. I am using a theme that has a homepage slider which spans across the entire content area. I have been asked to reduce the size of the slider and move the sidebar up next to it. I've attempted to call the sidebar in different and seemingly logical locations but the page breaks.

Any help would be much appreciated. index.php code here: http://pastebin.com/9FMWL7cC. Style sheet and site URL in comments if needed.

Comment: Style.css here http://pastebin.com/zChS6Q9J

Comment: site URL here: http://mefo1.ecin1prod1lnx1.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is to move `<div id="side">` outside of `<div id="content">`, so that you can properly position it next to the slider (`<div id="lof-container">`). Alternatively, you could do it with

```
#maincontent { overflow: visible; }
#side { margin-top: -300px; }
```

though this is pretty hackish.

Comment: Thanks Boone, I'll tinker around with this. Worst comes to worst, a little hackish may be called for.